# how to convert spm12 Matlab code to python?

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-compiler, matlab-spm

Spm12 , GUI interface which is built on Matlab compiler.It runs inside Matlab application.
Source code is available at **https://github.com/spm/spm12**

I need to covert the whole application into python language, any suggestions on how to get started on this?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point might be to look at what other people have already done. I haven't used nipy personally but colleagues have.

https://nipy.org/

https://nipype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: nipype is python wrapper , it cant execute independent of spm12-Matlab engine.